# var something = somethingElse.obj = somethingElse.obj || {} - what is this used for?

Tags: javascript, language-features

Sorry about the odd title... not sure how else to enquire about a language feature like this.

I was reading about [module patterns](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) when i came across this example when i came across this line of code.  It takes place in a closure for the example module pattern for maintaining a private state across different files when "loosely augmenting" a module.

### EDIT - included the rest of the module code

```
var MODULE = (function (my) { 
    var _private = my._private = my._private || {}, 
        _seal = my._seal = my._seal || function () { 
            delete my._private; 
            delete my._seal; 
            delete my._unseal; 
        }, 
        _unseal = my._unseal = my._unseal || function () { 
            my._private = _private; 
            my._seal = _seal; 
            my._unseal = _unseal; 
        }; 

    // permanent access to _private, _seal, and _unseal 

    return my; 
}(MODULE || {}));
```

I've tried to break it down but it's not adding up.

I started looking at it from right to left.  Now, i've seen the `var someVar = something || somethingElse` beore and i can only assume if something is not set (`false`, `null` etc) it evaluates this as a boolean expression and is set to the other value *(please confirm)*.

That's where i'm getting lost.  I can only assume the purpose for setting my._private is to set it to an empty object if it doesn't exist... but this is just conjecture.

**What's the purpose of setting my._private here?**

Answer (score 2):

Remember that every statement in Javascript evaluates to a value, even an assignment (which evaluates to the value which was assigned).

```
foo = bar = 3;
```

is the same as

```
foo = (bar = 3);
```

which is the same as

```
bar = 3;
foo = 3;
```

In your situation, `my._private` gets set to `{}` if it currently a falsey value, and then that value also gets assigned to the local `_private` variable

Comment: Your first statement is not really true in the way I think you mean. A statement doesn't "return" anything. I think your point is just that an assignment expression evaluates to the value on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Your conjecture is right, this:

```
var _private = my._private = my._private || {};
```

If `my._private` exists, it assigns it to the new `_private` variable.

If it's *not* there, it sets `my._private` to a new empty object and sets the new `_private` variable to the same reference.

---

*Why* is it setting it?  Presumably it's used later for some reason...but I can't say for sure without seeing the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do they use it anywhere else within the module?  If not, there really is not a purpose.  It could have been accomplished as `var _private = my._private || {};`